# How do I stop this <li> from collapsing?

Tags: html, css, debugging

[image]

Here yellow is `<li>` which is child of `<ul>` at the moment `<li>`  or `<ul>` don't have  `float:left` or  `display:inline`  as soon as I apply either float or display on `<li>` or `<ul>`

[image]

pink `<li>` which is child of nested `<ul>` changes it's appearance to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP82b.png)

```
<ul class="top_nav">
  <li>name

    <ul class="sub_nav">
      <li>name1 icnkdn ndkcnks kkncksn </li>
      <li>name2</li>
      <li>name3</li>
    </ul>

  </li>
  <li>home</li>
</ul>


.top_nav{
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
}

.top_nav > li  {
  padding:1em 2em;
  background:yellow;
  position:relative;
}

.sub_nav{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  background:green;
}

.sub_nav  li{
  display:block;
  background:pink;
  padding:1em 3em;
}
```

https://codepen.io/labeeb/pen/zRxoOR

Comment: Add please your HTML and CSS code

Comment: Forgot to add code, have updated question. Now remove down votes people @MonkeySupersonic

Comment: Have added please have a look @NatDavydova

Answer (score 4):

Your `.sub_nav` has `position: absolute;` that's why your `<li>` element is collapsed. Remove this property and everything will be ok.